# How to add Stripe ApplePay to woocommerce minicart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, applepay

I was able to hide Apple Pay button from single product page following way

```
// in functions.php
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_hide_payment_request_on_product_page', '__return_true' );
```

but now I want to add this button to minicart. Is there any hook or shortcode that allows placing Apple Pay button on minicart?
I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'mini_cart_stripe_button', 20 );
function mini_cart_stripe_button() {
    if( wp_is_mobile() ){
      //I'd like to add button here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but the snippet below makes the button appear on checkout.

`add_filter( 'wc_stripe_show_payment_request_on_checkout', '__return_true' );`

Also, here are some of the ApplyPay elements:

```
#wc-stripe-payment-request-wrapper

#wc-stripe-payment-request-button

#wc-stripe-payment-request-button-separator
```

Please let me know if you figure this one out. I would love to add this to the mini cart as well! Cheers.